# How to perform a non-blocking write to a USB HID device?

Tags: timeout, usb, nonblocking, hid, overlapped-io

I have a USB device that identifies as a HID peripheral. I communicate with it using the `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` Win32 API functions.

Occasionally the device gets "stuck" and does not respond, and needs to be unplugged and replugged. That's not a problem in and of itself, but it causes the call to `WriteFile` to block until the device is unplugged, and that *is* a problem.

I have read that I can use overlapped I/O to prevent this, but it doesn't work. The call to `WriteFileEx` still blocks!

Code fragment:

```
HANDLE hFCreateFileW(devicePath, NULL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
OVERLAPPED overlapped = {0};
overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
if (!WriteFileEx(hFile, buffer, length, &overlapped, nullptr))
    return FALSE;
for (int elapsed = 0; !HasOverlappedIoCompleted(&overlapped); elapsed++) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
    if (elapsed > READ_TIMEOUT_MS)
        return FALSE;
}
```

How can I force writes to timeout instead of blocking forever?

(NOTE: The solution needs to work on all versions of Windows from XP onwards.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [CreateFileW documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew#file_flag_overlapped) it is required to set `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in `dwFlagsAndAttributes` argument to enable non-blocking operations for a file.

So you should open file as

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(devicePath, NULL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
```

otherwise operations on file are still serialized even when `OVERLAPPED` is passed.

Comment: I *had* actually tried that in my real code, but somehow I'd added the flag to the wrong `CreateFile` call. Doh! Thank you, your answer prompted me to re-check my code and discover my mistake. It now works.